# html5 video: javascript resizing wrongly in window.onload, but correctly elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I am calling a function, using window.onload, which sets the style.height and style.width of video to the maximum possible in the window (while retain aspect ratio). When this is called in the onload event, the video has black bars on left and right sides, which remain when the browser is resized and seem to be part of the video (or its container?) from then on.

When i leave the "resizevid" function out of onload, and only call it in onresize, the black bars are not present.

Any ideas on how to fix this? what happens after the onload event which changes how the width of the video is interpreted? thank you so much if you can enlighten me!

url for full page: 
with resizevid in onload:
http://thebeach.name/video.html
with resizevid only in onresize:
http://thebeach.name/videores.html

excerpts of code:
style:

```
<style>
html, body, div, video{border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:black;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;}
video{width:100%}
</style>
```

html:

```
<body onresize="resizevid();" align=center>
<video align=center id="myvideo" autoplay loop>
</video>
</body>
```

script:

```
window.onload = function() {
changevid();
resizevid();
}

function resizevid(){

//find out the viewport size

var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined'){
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
 && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
{
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else
{
        viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}


//get the aspect ratio of the video

var vidwidth = document.getElementById('myvideo').offsetWidth;
var vidheight = document.getElementById('myvideo').offsetHeight;
var aspratio = vidheight/vidwidth;

//set video to full height, find correct width
function vidTooTall(){
    d=document.getElementById('myvideo');
    var newheight = viewportheight+'px';
    var newwidth = viewportheight/aspratio;
    newwidth = newwidth+'px';
    d.style.height = newheight;
    d.style.width = newwidth;
}

//set video to full width, find correct height
function vidTooWide(){
    d=document.getElementById('myvideo');
    var newwidth = viewportwidth+'px';
    var newheight = aspratio*viewportwidth;
    newheight = newheight+'px';
    d.style.height = newheight;
    d.style.width = newwidth;
}
//if windowheight/windowwidth < vidheight/vidwidth
//video is too tall, else video is too wide

if(viewportwidth*aspratio>viewportheight){
        vidTooTall();
    }
else{
        vidTooWide();
}

}
```